# Can pandas read a transposed CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Can `pandas` read a transposed CSV? Here's the file (note I'd also like to select a subset of columns):

```
A,x,x,x,x,1,2,3
B,x,x,x,x,4,5,6
C,x,x,x,x,7,8,9
```

Would like to get this DataFrame:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0, header=None).T
```

Comment: It looks like this is doing something funny with the column names - could this interact somehow with `usecols`?

Comment: Actually, maybe it's OK - I think I'm just seeing a row label (index 0) next to the column titles.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, if your file looks like this:

```
"some-line-you-want-to-skip"
A,x,x,x,x,1,2,3
B,x,x,x,x,4,5,6
C,x,x,x,x,7,8,9
```

It is possible to do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1, header=None).T   # Read csv, and transpose
df.columns = df.iloc[0]                                 # Set new column names
df.drop(0,inplace=True)                                 # Drop duplicated row
```

This will also end up with the df looking the way you want