# Save CSV to dictionary with a list as the value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV file looks something like this:

```
Version,1,2,3,4,5
Letter,A,B,C,D,E
```

Version and letter are both the keys I want in the dictionary which I read in using indexcol = 0. However, I want to save these values into a dictionary like this:

```
{Version: ["1,2,3,4,5"], Letter: ["A,B,C,D,E"]}
```

How would I do this using pandas?
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39381666/10393194

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the keys in rows, one simple way is to transpose the csv file and then converting columns to `list` followed by `zip` and to dictionary

```
df = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv").transpose()
dictionary = dict(zip(list(df.column_name1), list(df.column_name2)))
```

Other efficient way and if you have too many values in rows to enter each column name then you can try:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv").transpose().to_dict()
```