# Remove unamed:1 row from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

- I am reading the csv as `ldf_raw_data = pd.read_csv(lstr_file_path, index_col=0)`
- Dropping the `na` and using `T` to transpose it using `ldf_raw_two = (ldf_raw_salary_slip.dropna()).T`
- But I am getting `Unamed:1` as a multi-index. How can I remove it while performing transpose.
- Reading CSV

[image]

- After transpose

[image]

- Expected output

[image]

- Sample CSV

```
Salary Slip,
,
Employee Name,Aditi Aggarwal
Salary Period,June 2019
Employer Name,Hewlett Packard Enterprise
```

Comment: Can you provide a dataset or df to test and try?

Comment: @Roshan i have updated the question with the sample csv

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your csv file contains some information you don't need.

You could try just to skip those rows by using keyword `skiprows` and `header`.

```py
ldf_raw_data = pd.read_csv(lstr_file_path, index_col=0, skiprows=2, header=None).T
```

Source: [Can pandas read a transposed CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381475/can-pandas-read-a-transposed-csv)

Comment: ```skiprows=2``` is skipping the ```Employee Name``` also, so kept ```skiprows=1``` but the ```Unnamed: 1``` is still coming as multi-index.

Comment: Does it work by only doing this: `pd.read_csv(lstr_file_path, index_col=0, skiprows=2, header=None).T` ? Source/duplicate: [Can pandas read a transposed CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381475/can-pandas-read-a-transposed-csv)

Comment: The code mentioned by Ingebrigt is working for me. I can attach an image below.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ext-khadkro\Desktop\stack.csv",index_col = 0, skiprows = 2).T
```

Output:

[image]