# How to manipulate csv entries from horizontal to vertical

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have a csv with the following entries:

```
apple,orange,bannana,grape
10,5,6,4
four,seven,eight,nine
yes,yes,no,yes
3,5,7,4
two,one,six,nine
no,no,no,yes
2,4,7,8
yellow,four,eight,one
no,yes,no,no
```

I would like to make a new csv file with the following format and so on:

```
apple,10,four,yes
orange,5,seven,yes
bannana,6,seven,no
grape,4,nine,yes
apple,3,two,no
orange,5,one,no
bannana,7,six,no
grape,4,nine,yes
```

So after grape it starts at apple with the new values.

I have tried using pandas DataFrames but cant figure how to get the data formatted how I need it.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. The method "transpose" in pandas should help.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Sorry I made a mistake at the question. If you could kindly look at the new output block. A simple transpose will not work for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following in pure Python (`data.csv` name of input file):

```py
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open("data.csv", "r") as fin,\
     open("data_new.csv", "w") as fout:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(fin), csv.writer(fout)
    header = next(reader)
    length = len(header) - 1
    while (rows := list(islice(reader, length))):
        writer.writerows([first, *rest] for first, rest in zip(header, zip(*rows)))
```

Or with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = pd.concat(gdf.T for _, gdf in df.set_index(df.index % 3).groupby(df.index // 3))
df.reset_index().to_csv("data_new.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Output file `data_new.csv` for the provided sample:

```
apple,10,four,yes
orange,5,seven,yes
bannana,6,eight,no
grape,4,nine,yes
apple,3,two,no
orange,5,one,no
bannana,7,six,no
grape,4,nine,yes
apple,2,yellow,no
orange,4,four,yes
bannana,7,eight,no
grape,8,one,no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your dataframe in pandas as below.

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0, header=None).T
```

this question is already answered:

[Can pandas read a transposed CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381475/can-pandas-read-a-transposed-csv)

---

According to your new description, the problem is completely changed.
you need to split your dataframe to subsets and merge them.

```
# Read dataframe without header
df = pd.read_csv('your_dataframe.csv', header=None)

# Create an empty DataFrame to store transposed data
tr = pd.DataFrame()

# Create, transpose and append subsets to new DataFrame
for i in range(1,df.shape[0],3):
...     temp = pd.DataFrame()
...     temp = temp.append(df.iloc[0])
...     temp = temp.append(df.iloc[i:i+3])
...     temp = temp.transpose()
...     temp.columns = [0,1,2,3]
...     tr = d.append(temp)
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake at the question. If you could kindly look at the new output block. A simple transpose will not work for this.

Comment: @pythonic edited according to your new descriptions.

Comment: @pythonic your new descriptions changed problem completely. you have to consider, as a developer, it's important for you to analyse your problem well, before answer to it, or question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you.

```
df = pd.read_csv('<source file name>')
df.T.to_csv('<destination file name>')
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake at the question. If you could kindly look at the new output block. A simple transpose will not work for this.